# What is a "TDS conform" directory? (MikTeX on Windows)

Tags: miktex, tds

in many answers and hints to LaTeX questions regarding fonts, there is always the requirement for installing new fonts, to create a "TDS compliant" root directory.

If i follow these instructions and look up, for example on Windows with a Miktex installation, what a "TDS-compliant" directory should look like, it requests something: "THis does not look like an TDS-compliant directory. Please install one.."

He directs me to a documentation where following is claimed:

```
•bibtex
•doc
•fonts
•scripts
•tex
```

When i provide a directory with this structure (for example under C:\localtexmf) and try to add it via MikTeX console, he is still saying that exact this structure is "Not TDS-compliant". When i lookup the information, for example, as instructed by the answer in [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex/69484#69484)

it leads me to the information in [A Directory Structure for TeX Files](http://tug.org/tds/tds.html)
where a different "TDS-compliant" directory structure is propagated:

The top-level directories specified by the TDS are:

```
`tex' for TeX files (Section Macros).
`fonts' for font-related files (Section Fonts).
`metafont' for Metafont files which are not fonts (Section Non-font Metafont files).
`metapost' for MetaPost files (Section MetaPost).
`bibtex' for BibTeX files (Section BibTeX).
`scripts' for platform-independent executables (Section Scripts).
`doc' for user documentation (Section Documentation).
`source' for sources. This includes both traditional program sources ....
```

Besides the fact that is strange that there are different "TDS-compliant" directory structures, neither of this different "TDS-compliant" structures are working with MikTeX.

Is there another "TDS-compliant" structure which would work with MikTeX?

Comment: @moewe, yes, exactly that´s the reason i wrote this link in my comment

Comment: Ooops, missed that link, sorry.

Comment: Note that it is not enough to have only the top-level directories and then everything below that. You also need the sub-directory structure. Usually packages go into `tex/latex/<package name>`. How deep did you go?

Comment: @moewe. oh, i provided only the top level structure. But since there are different structures, i wonder which one will be the right TDS-structure.

Comment: I'm not sure how deep MikTeX goes to check that. I'd have thought it only becomes relevant once you actually put files somewhere, but I don't know. Do you have files in your TDS tree already? If so, where are they?

Comment: I provided the structure requested by MikTeX and the structure from the link, neither worked, but maybe, as you pointed out, because of the missing tree. I have to try it out, but have only time later this day. (But still wonder, which one is the "right" TDS-structure)

Comment: The first TDS structure is a subset of the second structure. So unless MikTeX somehow does not want to see certain directories of the TDS structure or requires certain directories to be present even though they are empty, I would have thought the top-level directories match. What you can't have is: `tex/mypkg.sty`, a package would have to live in `tex/latex/mypkg/mypkg.sty`. Could you just show us the *entire* structure of your current TDS tree?

Answer (score 5):

tds has a two-level structure: your files always go two folders down, in `tex\generic` or `tex\latex` or `fonts\tfm`.

I don't know the exact rules which miktex uses to check (one would need to check the source code for this), but I can add texmf tree if is has the minimal structure

```
 texmf\tex\latex
```

while only `texmf\tex` is rejected.